# Why shouldn't you use import all in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

So I recently started learning react and noticed that all the documentation has imports that look like else:

```
import { Apples, Bananas, Oranges } from 'fruits';
```

But while studying react I found that this syntax works just as well:

```
import * as Fruits from 'fruits';
```

**My Question:** Is there any performance loss or logical conflict with using the import all syntax?

If there is not then I will just keep using that syntax. I would rather be a little more verbose and not have to worry about making sure everything has been imported.

Comment: If you use a bundler that supports tree-shaking then the former would lead to potentially smaller result files.

Comment: "and not have to worry" --- you don't need to *worry*, your IDE should worry for you instead.

Comment: @zerkms That makes sense. I am using Webpack and I am fairly certain it does.

Comment: In addition to the answers given, the more specific imports make your code more self-documenting. This obviously doesn't help your app perform, but it might help your _brain_ perform when you look back at your code 6 months from now, and you're not sure whether `bananas` came from `fruits` or from `yellowThings`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually - it depends on the amount of exports from given module.

If you import e.g. `Lodash` you might not want to import whole library, you should import only these methods which you are going to use in your application:

`import { isEmpty, pickBy, orderBy } from 'lodash';`

to avoid performance loss and memory waste.

**However**, if your given module holds just a few methods or basically you are going to use **every** single export, then you can freely use that shortcut:

`import * as Fruits from 'fruits';`

**Note**: I suppose you are using `webpack 2`, which actually includes *three-shaking* algorithm which makes minifying the bundle possible.

Comment: "to avoid performance loss and memory waste." --- this should come with some evidence. Or at least something that makes it a point.

Comment: @zerkms Well, was testing it recently in my app, whole `lodash` weighs approx 70kb, while just few imported methods - 3-10kb depends on their complexity.

Comment: Then you should mention "tree-shaking" or alternative technology. Qualified import by itself does not improve anything.

Comment: @zerkms Is there somebody in this world who's not using React with Webpack?

Comment: Sure: people who don't use react clientside and only for SSR (static websites)

Comment: @zerkms But there's `reactjs` tagged that's why I suppose that asker is actually using react with babel.

Comment: I understand that: you totally can use reactjs without webpack. And this chat takes too long, I'm out :-)

Comment: Compared to the other 2 this is the best advice. In my case I have few libraries in use, some of which I am only using a part of and some which I know I will be using all or at least nearly all of the components.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to use the first way. At least for one thing: `Always write explicitly what you want to use`. It's a best practice in all framework / language.

If you have some tree-shaking, some unused module won't be loaded and everything should be good (like @zerkms said). 
But it's in the best world case, even the best tree shaking isn't perfect and you could have some import still being imported even if you don't use them. 
If your project is 'small' it should be ok. If in your project you load hundreds stuff, it could be a little bit different.

And when you will build your project, you will loose time with the tree-shaking analysis too.

So just because you don't want to "loose time by writing two words" you will loose time on every build and maybe have a performance impact

Answer (score 1):

That depends upon what module bundler you're using. If you're using > webpack 2.0 as your bundler then it would affect the bundle size because :

```
import { Apples, Bananas, Oranges } from 'fruits';
```

will only bring `Apples`, `Bananas` and `Oranges` from the file as webpack 2.0 uses `tree-shaking` algorithm for optimisation. Also, in that case, you need to take care that you don't do any `default export` in your file, instead you export `const` because named exports would suffice that.

```
import * as Fruits from 'fruits';
```

would just bring everything declared in `fruits` file.

I found this great conversation with Dan Abramov on twitter and that should help you.

> https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/927835086577430529

**EDIT**

In case of lodash, you'd probably want to use [babel-lodash-plugin](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash). If you'd use that then you won't have to do

```
import {isEmpty, isUndefined} from 'lodash';
```

and you can do

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

as it doesn't bring the whole library for you.