# Best way to import from different files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have many shared client only and global functions. Now i import them in one file and export from there so i can import them in app like this:

Some component_1.js

```
import {
  Input,
  useRole,
  PopupContext,
  ProfileContext,
  PriceButton
} from 'shared'
import { regexp, dashUrl } from 'global'
```

Some component_100.js

```
import {
  theme,
  data,
} from 'shared'
import { regexp } from 'global
```

ReExport shared.js (global is the same, but with another functions):

```
// Компоненты
export { Button } from './components/Button'
export { Input } from './components/Input'
export { InputNumber } from './components/InputNumber'
export { SearchBox } from './components/SearchBox'
export { Select } from './components/Select'
export { Sex } from './components/Sex'
export { Textarea } from './components/Textarea'
export { Avatar } from './components/Avatar'
export { Cover } from './components/Cover'
export { Loading } from './components/Loading'
export { NeedProfile } from './components/NeedProfile'
export { SystemBlock } from './components/SystemBlock'
export { Modal } from './components/Modal'
export { DatePicker } from './components/DatePicker'
export { Tooltip } from './components/Tooltip'
export { PriceButton } from './components/PriceButton'
export { Highlight } from './components/Highlight'

// Иконки
export { AvatarIcon } from './icons/AvatarIcon'
export { PatreonIcon } from './icons/PatreonIcon'
export { CoverIcon } from './icons/CoverIcon'
export { CookiesIcon } from './icons/CookiesIcon'
export { EnergyIcon } from './icons/EnergyIcon'
export { FemaleIcon } from './icons/FemaleIcon'
export { ItIcon } from './icons/ItIcon'
export { ArrowIcon } from './icons/ArrowIcon'
export { KnigAmIcon } from './icons/KnigAmIcon'
export { MaleIcon } from './icons/MaleIcon'
export { MoonIcon } from './icons/MoonIcon'
export { EyeIcon } from './icons/EyeIcon'
export { PlusIcon } from './icons/PlusIcon'
export { PagesIcon } from './icons/PagesIcon'
export { BookIcon } from './icons/BookIcon'
export { SunIcon } from './icons/SunIcon'
export { VkIcon } from './icons/VkIcon'
export { CookieIcon } from './icons/CookieIcon'
export { LinkIcon } from './icons/LinkIcon'
export { StarIcon } from './icons/StarIcon'
export { SettingsIcon } from './icons/SettingsIcon'

// Use
export { marked } from './modules/marked'

//Функции
export { kFormatter } from './functions/kFormatter'
export { numEnds } from './functions/numEnds'
export { binaryClosest } from './functions/binaryClosest'

// Хуки
export { useRole } from './hooks/useRole'
export { useDebounce } from './hooks/useDebounce'

//Данные
export { defaultTheme } from './data/defaultTheme'
```

What i curious about, is there maybe a better way to do it?

Maybe is best way just to use * in components?

```
import * from 'shared'
import * from 'global'
```

Import is reference, not a copy, so there is no increase in bundle size if you at least one time use module (there is no difference if you import Button one time or 100).

Comment: Use * in components is not a good way. You can create recursive call and complexe error to debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't you use import all in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294904/why-shouldnt-you-use-import-all-in-es6)

Comment: I personally would avoid creating these types of global modules,.  Yes, with modern package managers tree-shaking should optimise unused exports, but make sure no side effects are enabled in say webpack.  But doing something like this -> `import DatePicker from "@mylib/date-picker"`  is really not that bad is it?.  Also try and avoid mixed cased module names, `date-picker` instead of `DatePicker`, it just avoids problems when doing cross platform builds, and other strange errors.

Comment: @Keith how then i can solve a problem with export if i have 100 components and without shared (with alias) this will get me nuts to import every time.

Comment: If you use units that need to import 100's of components in 1 unit, then I'd say your not doing it right.  One massive rule of Javascript that's really handy, keep your units small & concise.  This was kind of the philosophy of NPM.  For example if I see units going over a few hundred lines of code, I will step back I see how I can re-factor this into smaller units.  In the long run this really pay's dividends, not only does making editing easier, it kind of also make code more re-usable.  When I first started using JS, I did exactly the same as you, I really wished I never.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand something. I have like 100 components (like Avatar, Subscribes) that made out of smaller shared components and functions (somewhere around 1 to 15 for component. Total amount of small ones is like 50) like Button, Input, isInteger. If i will not have global index.js re-export file for small components, than i will need to import them relative to component one after one - this is nuts!

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Import is reference, not a copy, so there is no increase in bundle size if you at least one time use module (there is no difference if you import Button one time or 100). And as it's my library, i use all of theme at least once.

Comment: `than i will need to import them relative to component one after one`, not sure what this means here,.. If I do `import {MyMassiveComponent} from "@mylib/massive-component`,  I don't need to import all the other small components it's made of,.. I don't have to worry about relative paths either, I try to avoid relative paths as much as possible, using `node_modules` resolve logic, this is easily done.  Anyway, marked as primarily opinion-based, as doing what your doing is fine, if that's what you feel comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern that I have tried to follow is having an `index` file that manages the exports within a given folder. For example, given a folder structure:

```
src
 |---components
 |  |---InputNumber
 |  |---SearchBox
 |  |---Select
 |---data
 |  |---TestData
 |---utils
    |---MyHelper
```

I might have an `index.js` file in `components` like this:

```js
export * from './InputNumber';
export * from './SearchBox';
export * from './Select';
```

And in `src` I might have an `index.js` file like this:

```js
export * from './components';
export * from './data';
export * from './utils';
```

This breaks up the responsibility of exporting to the directory/package itself. `components` controls what gets exported from itself, and so on.

Comment: So it's the same as my example, just with more separation. Maybe i'm lazy, but i don't want to type 5 lines to import instead one for react 100 components.